# How to make this overlay full height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to make simple gallery with some jQuery.

When user click the image its will show the images without directly to the image link.

The problem is when I click it i get full overlay screen but when I clicked the third and fourth picture its will not given full screen overlay.

You can try my code at here.

http://codepen.io/jakzaizzat/pen/zskCf

```
//Jquery Object
var $overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');

var $image = $('<img>');

var $caption =$('<p></p>');



$overlay.append($image);

$overlay.append($caption);

$('body').append($overlay);

//1 Click image 

    $('.container ul li a').click(function(event){
    //1.1 Stop prevent default
    event.preventDefault();

    //2.1 SHow image

    $imageLocation = $(this).attr('href');
    console.log($imageLocation);

    $image.attr('src',$imageLocation);

    //2.2 Show caption (use alt)

    $getCaption = $(this).children('img').attr('alt');

    $caption.text($getCaption);
    //2 Show Overlay

    $overlay.fadeIn('slow');




    });

//3 Click image again
    //3.1 hide overlay
    ($overlay).click(function(){

        $overlay.fadeOut('slow');
    })
```

Thanks.

Comment: I usually make the overlay "position: fixed".

Answer (score 0):

remove top attribute from this class  :

```
.container {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
/* height: 800px; */
max-width: 60%;
border: 9px solid white;
border-radius: 10px;
list-style: none;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
/* top: 70px; */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do, I would change the overlay's `position` to `fixed`:

```
#overlay{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed; 
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add css position: relative 
to body tag(Inside IFrame)